# Selecting feature by coordinates from the Vector Tile Layer using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, latitude-longitude, features, select-by-location, vector-tiles

I have a vector tile layer in QGIS, loaded from:  [https://cdn.kadastr.live/tiles/maps/kadastr/land_polygons/{z}/{x}/{y}.pbf](https://cdn.kadastr.live/tiles/maps/kadastr/land_polygons/%7Bz%7D/%7Bx%7D/%7By%7D.pbf).

How to select a single feature of this layer by coordinates, in PyQGIS?

I am trying to use `selectByGeometry` method, but it is not working.

```py
latitude = 48.23117391
longitude = 22.74110528

layer = iface.activeLayer()

iface.mapCanvas().refresh()
geom = QgsGeometry.fromPointXY(QgsPointXY(longitude, latitude))

canvas = iface.mapCanvas()
context = QgsSelectionContext()
context.setScale(10000)

print(layer.selectedFeatureCount())
layer.selectByGeometry(geom,context)#,context,behavior= Qgis.SelectBehavior.AddToSelection,relationship= Qgis.SelectGeometryRelationship.Intersect,flags=Qgis.SelectionFlags(2))
print(layer.selectedFeatureCount())
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your vector tile layer is in EPSG:3857 but your lat and long are in geographic degrees (EPSG:4326). You need to transform the selection geometry to the layer crs.

Additionally, I found it necessary to use a polygon selection geometry. I created a `QgsGeometry` from the bounding box of a very small buffer applied to the transformed point. To be honest I'm not sure why this is necessary - looking at the [source code](https://api.qgis.org/api/qgsvectortilelayer_8cpp_source.html#l00662) it seems that it should work with a single point selection geometry, though the [tests](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/4cf834499bceda58a9081e3ea44f04a6d6f61cb7/tests/src/python/test_qgsvectortile.py#L139) for `QgsVectorTileLayer` use a polygon selection geometry.

This worked for me:

```py
from qgis.utils import iface
from qgis.core import (QgsGeometry, QgsPointXY, QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem,
                       QgsCoordinateTransform, QgsProject, QgsSelectionContext)

latitude = 48.23117391
longitude = 22.74110528

layer = iface.activeLayer()

geom = QgsGeometry.fromPointXY(QgsPointXY(longitude, latitude))

def transformed_geom(g):
    pt_geom = QgsGeometry().fromWkt(g.asWkt())
    xform = QgsCoordinateTransform(QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem('epsg:4326'), layer.crs(), QgsProject.instance())
    pt_geom.transform(xform)
    bb_geom = QgsGeometry().fromRect(pt_geom.buffer(0.001, 1).boundingBox())
    return bb_geom

canvas = iface.mapCanvas()
context = QgsSelectionContext()
context.setScale(canvas.scale())

print(layer.selectedFeatureCount())

layer.selectByGeometry(transformed_geom(geom), context)
                        
print(layer.selectedFeatureCount())
```

[image]

And at higher zoom level:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This works fine for me. Could you please explain why do you use:
 `pt_geom = QgsGeometry().fromWkt(g.asWkt())` ?

Comment: @СтьопаБрич, it's just copying the input geometry so that the original `geom` is not modified.

Comment: I still do not know why the creation of a tiny buffer around a point is necessary ... it precisely says `bool isPointOrRectangle`

Comment: `QgsGeometry(g)` also creates a copy of a geometry and will be more efficient because it saves on a roundtrip through WKT.

Answer (score -1):

This is all you need to select all the features of a layer at a certain point:

```
latitude = 48.23117391
longitude = 22.74110528
layer = iface.activeLayer()

point = QgsPointXY(longitude, latitude)
rect = QgsRectangle(point, point)

layer.selectByRect(rect)
```

Comment: This solution is not applicable for the `QgsVectorTileLayer`, otherwise you will get this: `"AttributeError: 'QgsVectorTileLayer' object has no attribute 'selectByRect'"`